# Import error on 'minpack2' from 'scipy.optimize'

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to import minpack2 from the Scipy package within a python script and get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "markowitz.py", line 2, in <module>
    from scipy import optimize
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/__init__.py", line 232, in <module>
    from .optimize import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 37, in <module>
    from .linesearch import (line_search_wolfe1, line_search_wolfe2,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/linesearch.py", line 18, in <module>
    from scipy.optimize import minpack2
ImportError: cannot import name 'minpack2' from 'scipy.optimize' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/__init__.py)
```

My python version is: Python 3.7.2 (default, Jan 11 2019, 21:31:15)  [GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux

Scipy was installed using pip and is on version 0.18.

Comment: What scipy version are you using (`print(scipy.__version__)`)? Is this a conda setup?

Comment: No, its not conda. My scipy version is 0.18

Comment: Did you `pip install scipy` or called `setup.py`

Comment: I used pip install scipy

Comment: I‘m wondering why your scipy version is so old then. Pip should should get 1.2.0 according to the package index. You can find various google hits to people having import problems from scipy, mainly in github issues. No general solution, but often upgrading to the latest version helps - esp. while you‘re running a pretty new Python release. Which linux distro are you running?